# Experience with collaborative sound design?

Tags: sound-design, workflow, collaboration, interactive

I'm a sound designer with an interactive design group. We do public installations that often involve generating audio based on public interactions.
I do tech, system design, and more and more, sound. Our next project is big, and will most likely involve more than one sound designer. I've never collaborated with another sound designer.

The other sound designer is in the same city, but we will be in different studios most of the time.

For anybody who has some experience with this, have you found a general workflow that makes sense? What works, what doesn't?

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest at least from more of a video based standpoint is to have a meeting and have each person concentrate on a certain aspect of the sound design.  Maybe 1 person could do the more natural sounds and another the more designed sounds.  You can probably share mixdowns everyday (or as often as makes sense)  If you have worked together and know the others strengths and weakness thats probably even better.  That way the more musical person can handle the more musical sound design elements etc.

I know some people like to switch and give the other a shot at the sounds they designed but that is probably only possible if your using the same software and plugs and have the time.